# How to change de jre enviroment on websphere 8.0?

Tags: java, websphere, java-6

I have an App on java, I've created the war file and I uploaded it on WebSphere 8.0 but when I run the app WebSphere shows this: [Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBUco.png)

These errors reference to:

```
<% 
    int proceso = (Integer) request.getAttribute("proceso");
    String id = (String) request.getAttribute("id");
    int user = (Integer) request.getAttribute("user");
    String ruta = (String) request.getAttribute("ruta");
    String carpeta = (String) request.getAttribute("carpetaServer");
    String budgetId = (String) request.getAttribute("budgetId");

    List<String> encabezado = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("encabezado");
    List<Combo> secciones = (List<Combo>) request.getAttribute("secciones");
    List<Combo> imagenes = (List<Combo>) request.getAttribute("imagenes");

%>
```

I use java 1.6 so I dont know what is the problem. I guess is jre version, but I could not find which version is use.

The SystemOut.log show this:

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere Platform 8.0.0.0 [BASE 8.0.0.0 n1118.03] running with process name XMBX248PCNode03Cell\XMBX248PCNode03\server1 and process id 7404
Host Operating System is Windows 7, version 6.1
Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer
user.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/java/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/installedChannels;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/web/help;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\java\jre\bin\default;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\java\jre\bin;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere8\AppServer\java\jre\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Informix\Client-SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk7\lib;C:\Bitnami\subversion-1.8.16-0\subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.81\bin;;
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb626fp1-20110419.00
```

Version of websphere:
[Version Websphere 8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX6CU.png)

Comment: The errors in the screenshot definitely indicate that it doesn't see the code as Java 5 (or higher). How are you building the war file? Do you have any "precompile JSPs" options selected?

Comment: (Also, realize that your Integer to int "unboxing" can throw a NullPointerException if the attribute isn't found on the request.)

Comment: Yes, I selected precompile JSPs option in websphere. However  its ok, already I deployed the war successfuly. In netbeans clean and build options were using jre7, so, I changed to jdk 6 in compile options and works.

Answer (score 0):

You've never applied any maintenance to your application server, so it is the "point 0" code from 2011.  I''d suggest applying the latest available JDK and application server maintenance which come in the very first archive here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042746

While you're at it, I'd suggest upgrading to 8.5.5 or 9.0 releases as the 8.0 release you're on will be out of service next year and is
permanently stuck at Java 6.

Comment: Actually i have the last fix pack for was8.0 (fix 13) I just make the app with tomcat, but upload it in was 8.0 is thing of the corporation. I cant only upgrade it. So, if I have the latest fix pack and java 6, whats the problem?

Comment: Does "having" it mean something other than running it?

WebSphere Platform 8.0.0.0 [BASE 8.0.0.0 n1118.0]